# PHP Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): 'utc' is invalid

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I found in the logs this error message:

```
PHP Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'utc' is invalid
```

How to solve it? I'm using PHP-FPM on Ubuntu 13.10 and nginx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that you need to use "UTC", not "utc".  The timezones are, most likely, case sensitive.

Edit:
Quickly playing around with php -a confirms this.